# Angular 2 inject a class into a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to inject in my service a class with my config params.

I did the sample code below, but it is not working:

```
import { Config } from '../app.constants';

console.log(Config); // here i can access to my properties of config

@Injectable()
export class MyService {


  protected config: Config;

  constructor(protected _http: Http, @Inject(Config) _configuration: Config) {
    console.log(this.config); // undefined
    console.log(_configuration); // undefined
}
```

I think I didnt understood the scope and inject process of angular 2. 
How can I access to my class Config inside of my service MyService?

EDIT :

Here is my module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';

import { MyService } from './my.service';
import { Config } from '../app.constants';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyService
  ],
  exports: [
    MyService
  ],
  providers: [
    MyService,
    Config
  ]
})
export default class MyModule {}
```

and here is my config :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Config {
  public Port: number = 1234;
  public Server: string = "http://my-server.com";
}
```

The service MyService is not directly called, but I extended it like that:

@Injectable()
export class TestService extends MyService{
...
}

which is imported like that :

```
import { TestService } from '../service/test.service';
//some modules are from ng2-admin, we can ignore them
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgaModule,
    TestRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    TestComponent,
    HoverTable
  ],
  exports: [
    TestComponent,
    HoverTable
  ],
  providers: [
    TestService
  ]
})
export default class TestModule {}
```

and finally my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-list',
  template: require('./test.html')
})
export class TestComponent {


   constructor(protected service: TestService) {
      //console.log(service);

   }
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log( this. _configuration )`?

Comment: i havent affected _configuration in my class, it is just a local property of my constructor.

Comment: @estus i edited my question with a lot of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export class MyService {

  protected config: Config;

  constructor(protected _http: Http, @Inject(Config) _configuration: Config) {
    console.log(this.config); // undefined
    console.log(_configuration); // undefined
  }
}
```

You never initialize the config field anywhere, so it's undefined. All you need is

```
export class MyService {

  protected config: Config;

  constructor(protected _http: Http, _configuration: Config) {
    this.config = _configuration;
  }
}
```

Or simply

```
export class MyService {

  protected config: Config;

  constructor(protected _http: Http, protected config: Config) {
  }
}
```

Since MyService is a service, it must be added to the providers of your module, and not to the declarations (which is for components, pipes and directives):

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MuleService,
    Config,
    MyService
  ]
})
```

If you want to only use TestService as a service, and not MyService, make sure that TestService has a constructor that takes all the arguments that must be injected, too:

```
constructor(http: Http, config: Config) {
  super(http, config);
}
```

Comment: i agree that my param config is never set, at the begining i was filling it as you did but as said in the line below, even console.log(_configuration); is undefined so issue is outside of my constructor. for the providers i ve defined it also as you said, but it is not possible to access to my config even like that. I will try to edit TestService as you said right now!

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then provide a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: I have  Can't resolve all parameters for TestService, even when i add Config and MyService as declaration and import of my test module. will try to do a plunker if noone has idea tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet , Thanks for your answer. It is ok now. I made a sample plunker but i didnt figured our to make it work, but I still fixed it on my side ! 
thanks

Comment: for those who need inspiration, it is done like this https://plnkr.co/edit/kciq3EAdjUYSH3m66ScT